# Svg changes layout of my webpage only in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have built a beautiful website, with a lot of svg's. The page is extremely responsive because off bootstrap. Probally one of the best website I have ever built. However, when I test my site in Internet Explorer 11 the svg's mess up my layout. I have tried using javascript to load a new css file when on internet explorer. The code shows in the url true when in IE, and false in other browsers. However my css file is always replaced with the styleie.css (internet explorer style sheet) and dose not show my normal style sheet in chrome. What do you recommend? Thanks in advance. Specifically for IE-11.

```
window.location.hash = !!window.MSInputMethodContext;
  if (window.location.hash) 
      {   var $head = $("head");
          var $headlinklast = $head.find("link[rel='stylesheet']:last");
          var linkElement = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/styleie.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>";
          if ($headlinklast.length){
             $headlinklast.after(linkElement);
          }
          else {
             $head.append(linkElement);
          }
   }
```